# Creating Laravel Forum with Chatter Package

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have followed each step from https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter but got error during migration, as well as php artisan db:seed --class=ChatterTableSeeder command also didnt worked
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I forked the original Chatter repository (it was left out) as a base and created a completely new, single-page forum using Laravel resources API, Tailwind CSS and Vue.js. It's easy to install and easier to extend.

Check it at **[Chatter-laravel/core](https://github.com/Chatter-Laravel/core)** and check a **[demo here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIaEsMWBV28)**

Answer (score 0):

Laravel packages help any website in so many ways. Their implementation provides you with plenty of benefits.

To help you with the Laravel Packages, Here are [Top 35+ Useful Laravel Packages to Improve Website Performance](https://windzoon.com/blog/laravel-packages/)

Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).